# Excel - How do I round a date type to the next hour if it is more than one minute

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

So I have a hh:mm:ss date type and I want to round it to the next hour if it is even 1 minute above 0.

Example: 14:01 -> 15:00
11:24 -> 12:00

Tried using =MROUND(A1,"1:00") but it just rounds it to the closest hour not to the next hour as I need.

Answer (score 2):

Add almost 30 minutes and it'll get you what you need.

```
=MROUND(A1+TIME(0,29,59),"1:00")
```